# Printing 2-d Array

Tags: c, arrays

I want to print the row major using function

the code is given below

```
void rowmajor(int array,int row, int column)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; ++j)
        {
            printf("A(%d,%d) =\n", i+1,j+1);
            printf("%d\n", array[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

In the main function, the code for printing 2-d array is properly working but it's not working this code.

The error generated is as given

```
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror    matrix.c  -lcs50 -lm -o matrix
matrix.c:16:25: error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
```

Comment: `array` is an `int` type? Really?

Comment: Due to [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) the expression `&array[i][j]` is actually equal to `&(array[i][j])`. And since `array` is not, as the name would suggest, an array (or a pointer) you get the error because an `int` value can't be used with a subscript (like an array).

Comment: I would guess the problem is that the value is not an array, pointer, or vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have passed the parameter the wrong way.

```
void rowmajor(int row, int column, int array[][column])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; ++j)
        {
            printf("A(%d,%d) =\n", i+1,j+1);
            printf("%d\n", &array[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

When you pass an array it decays into `int (*)[column]`  but you considered it to be of type `int` which it is not that's why compiler complained.

Remember when you pass an array, you need to specify the `column` part otherwise you will run into errors.

Also you are passing wrong parameter to `printf`. In case of printing it will be

```
   printf("%d",array[i][j]);
```

`&array[i][j]` means the address where of the element `arr[i][j]`.

<sup>And also there is  one thing a beginner face - keep in mind an array (`int[row][column]`) when passed to function is not `int**`</sup>

<sup>Interesting Note:
 You can pass the array to the function as `void rowmajor(int row, int column, int array[][column])`, `void rowmajor(int row, int column, int array[row][column])` is better in case of type safety. 
As mentioned by Lundin, suppose you declare an 2d array `int array[2][3]` then in case you call it like this `rowmajor(3,3,array)` then in first case it wouldn't generate any warning but in second case it would.</sup>

Comment: `int array[row][column]`, although equivalent to `int array[][column]`, may give additional type safety when using static analysers. Therefore, the former style is preferred.

Comment: @Lundin.: You mean the int array[row][column] is better? Can you show a reference.

Comment: Suppose you call the function like this: `int arr[2][3]; rowmajor(3,3,arr);`. Here it would be statically possible to raise a warning, but it wouldn't be possible if the function was declared as `void rowmajor(int row, int column, int (*array)[column])` or similar.

Comment: @Lundin.: Nice really. A stupid question - is there any static analyzer which does this (maybe I want to know the name)? (Or any compiler do this as an extended functionality?)

Comment: `rowmajor(array[row][column], row, column);`

 I have used this argument and  called `rowmajor ()` in main() , but still I can't figure out the problem after changing the above code as corrected by you.
Please don't consider silly mistakes as I'm new in programming and need to learn more.
@coderredoc

Comment: I corrected the code as below:

`void rowmajor(int array[][column],int row, int column)`

but the error is 

`matrix.c:9:27: error: use of undeclared identifier 'column'`

Comment: @coderredoc Not sure, I currently only have access to an older version of LDRA Testbed, which does not warn for this. But there's really no reason why it shouldn't. As a side note, if you pass the whole array by pointer, `func (int row, int column, int (*array)[row][column])` then it turns type safe even at compiler level. This is a trick to increase type safety at the expense of more obscure code.

Comment: @RishavPandey Why don't you take _the code from this answer_ and try that instead? The dimensions of the array need to be on the left side of the array parameter.